# Error "Bad address" when reading from message queue on Linux

Tags: c, linux, unix, message-queue

I have assignment when I need to write simple time server and a client using Linux message queue. The server opens a message queue and the client sends a request with his PID (message with type 1) and the server reads that message and sends a message with type of PID (taken from the message read). I put all the code below because I don't know where I made the mistake. I'm not Linux programming expert. Don't even know if I written server correct.

File that is included by server and client (I need to write it in this way).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define QUEUE 100
#define PERM_ALL 0777

typedef struct my_msgbuf {
    long mtype;
    int pid;
} ClientMessage;

typedef struct my_msgbuf2 {
    long mtype;
    struct tm time;
} TimeMessage;
```

Server

```
int m_queue;

void cleanup(int signum) {
    if (msgctl(m_queue, IPC_RMID, NULL) == -1) {
        printf("Something happen on clean up\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    exit(signum);
}

int main() {
    ClientMessage pid_message;
    TimeMessage t;
    time_t clock;
    struct tm *cur_time;

    if ((m_queue = msgget(QUEUE, PERM_ALL | IPC_CREAT)) == -1) {
        printf("Can't create and open message queue\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("created message queue = %d\n", m_queue);
    fflush(stdout);
    //t = malloc(sizeof(TimeMessage));
    signal(SIGINT, cleanup);

    while (1) {
        if (msgrcv(m_queue, &pid_message, sizeof(pid_message.pid), 1, 0) == -1) {
            break;
        } else {
            t.mtype = pid_message.pid;
            clock = time(NULL);
            cur_time = localtime(&clock);
            memcpy(&t.time, cur_time, sizeof(struct tm));
            msgsnd(m_queue, &t, sizeof(struct tm), 0);
        }
    }

    cleanup(0);
}
```

Client

```
int main() {
    int m_queue;
    TimeMessage *t;
    ClientMessage client;

    if ((m_queue = msgget(QUEUE, PERM_ALL)) == -1) {
        perror("Error in opening queue");
        exit(1);
    }

    client.mtype = 1;
    client.pid = getpid();

    while (1) {
        if (msgsnd(m_queue, &client, sizeof(client.pid), 0) == -1) {
            perror("Error sending to queue");
            exit(1);
        } else {
            if (msgrcv(m_queue, t, sizeof(struct tm), client.pid, 0) == -1) {
                perror("Error reading from queue");
                exit(1);
            }   
            printf("time: %d:%d:%d\n", t->time.tm_hour, t->time.tm_min, t->time.tm_sec);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Both program compile without errors but client return "Error reading from queue" msgrcv is returning -1.

Comment: Suggestion: When working with APIs which set `errno` (like message queue APIs in your case) it might be a good idea to use [`perror` or `strerror`](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/perrorman.html)

Comment: thanks @another.anon.coward I was wondering why examples uses perror

Comment: Now msgrcv return "Bad address"

Comment: That means "The address pointed to by msgp (buffer) isn't accessible.", it appears you have not allocate memory for `t`, how about trying to change `TimeMessage *t` to `TimeMessage t` & pass `&t` instead of `t`?

Comment: Also the size your are passing in `msgrcv` seems to be incorrect, change `sizeof(struct tm)` to `sizeof t` (assuming you have changed `*t` to `t`)

Comment: @another.anon.coward It work now please put you second comment as answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After adding the `perror` it appears that you have got the error stating `"Bad Address"` (*EFAULT*)  which means that  "The address pointed to by *msgp* (buffer) isn't accessible". From the code it appears that there has been no memory allocated to `TimeMessage *t` so you can either allocate memory or just change it to `TimeMessage t` and pass `&t` instead of `t` to `msgrcv`. Also size should be `sizeof t` (assuming the change from `*t` to `t`, or `sizeof(TimeMessage)` for `*t`) instead of `sizeof(struct tm)` (& obviously you would change `printf` statement accordingly)
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I add `t = malloc(sizeof(TimeMessage));` and it work.